# OpenStack Floating ip assoicated to virtual ip

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, keepalived

I am trying to perform a POC,
I have configured a virtual ip ( implemented by keepalived) that will be moving from vm1 to vm2 in case vm1 in not avilbale.

Details:
vm1    - 10.0.0.1(internal), 192.168.10.10(floating ip)
vm1    - 10.0.0.2(internal), 192.168.10.11(floating ip)
vip    - 10.0.0.110(virtual ip -internal)
vipEXT - 192.168.10.13(virtual ip -floating)

The internal part is working fine, I followed the instruction and was able to make the vip-10.0.0.110 address to migrate from vm1 to vm2 in case vm1 fails,
I have created a floating ip with 192.168.10.13 address and assoicated with the vip port but still cant access to vip(10.0.0.110) from vipEXT(192.168.10.13).
The status of the of this floating ip is Down,

Do you have any sugestions?

[image: Floating IPs status]

Comment: Which neutron plugin is in use in this environment?

Comment: We use 'Open vSwitch agent' and 'L3 agent'

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve it by following this blog:
[https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/11/highly-available-vips-openstack-vmsrrp

This setup was working only after I created a new Router using the '--centralized' flag instead the '--distributed' that come as default in my case.